# Can I replace U1 (79L05) -5V 1MA with MC7905CT -5V 1A without problem?

Tags: voltage-regulator

I am assembling a metal detector kit of parts. 
http://silverdog.co.uk/images/BuildingMinipulseRevD.pdf

At the end of stage 1 which involves building is 'a simple linear regulator that provides the -5V power supply'. I was getting a test reading of -8.62V and not -5V.

So I have concluded that I should replace the voltage regulator U1 (79L05).
The question is can I replace U1 (79L05) which is -5V 1MA with a MC7905CT which is -5V 1A or is this likely to cause problems elsewhere on the circuit board.

Th only other issue is that the 'legs' on the  MC7905CT which is -5V 1A need to be gently filed to allow them through the holes in the board.

Why not simply buy another U1 (79L05)....I am in Morocco and they aren't that easy to find.

I hope this is clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have the space and have checked the pinout (79xx negative regulator pinout is not the same as 78xx positive regulator pinout) then go ahead. BTW, a 79L05 is usually a 100mA device, not 1MA (thats 100 milli-amps, not 1 mega-amp)

Answer (score 1):

Many variants of the 79L05 and 7905 need a minimum load, otherwise they produce a too high (absolute value) output voltage. Step one operates the 79L05 *completely* unloaded, which can cause -8.6V output even on a perfectly working part. If with a 1mA load (5k resistor) the voltage drops to -5V, your chip is OK.

Answer (score 0):

You need input and output capacitors on the 78/79xx range of regulators and you need to be aware that both devices have different pin outs and this could be your mistake. So, try checking the wiring diagram in the data sheet and measure the output off load just to confirm it is producing -5V.

Actually the pin out for both 78 and 79 devices is easy to remember.

Pin 1 is most positive voltage (0V on a 79xx and input voltage on a 78xx)
Pin 2 is most negative voltage (0V on a 78xx and input voltage on a 79xx)

The 7905 can naturally replace the 79L05